# Formatting the date after outputting from list

Tags: list, javascript, date-time

I have outputted a date type from a list of mine like so

```
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        upStartDate.push(oListItem.get_item('EventDate'));      

}
```

and outputted it onto my page like so :

```
    for (i=0; i<upStartDate.length;i++){

test += upStartDate[i]+'</br>';
}

document.getElementById("addNextEventHere").innerHTML = test;
```

but the date comes out like `Wed Jul 23 01:00:00 UTC+0100 2014` is there anyway I can format it so it is just the date so `23rd July 2014`

Comment: Have you tried http://momentjs.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = new Date("Wed Jul 23 01:00:00 UTC+0100 2014");

getFormattedDateWithOrdinal = function (date) {
    var d = new Date(date);
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var months = new Array("January", "February", "March","April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

    var ord = "";

    if (curr_date == 3 || curr_date == 23) {
        ord = "rd";
    }
    else if (curr_date == 1 || curr_date == 21 || curr_date == 31) {
        ord = "st";
    }
    else if (curr_date == 2 || curr_date == 22) {
        ord = "nd";
    }
    else {
        ord = "th";
    }

    return (curr_date + ord + " " + months[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear());
};

console.log(getFormattedDateWithOrdinal(d));
```